# ASP Identity 2.0.0 usermanager calling wrong method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have implemented a custom UserStore for my ASP MVC project (with Identity 2.0.0, which I use for it allows the use of integer keys).

The Usermanager is not custom implemented, but  the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Usermanager implementation.
When I call:

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(User, model.Password);
```

In my accountcontroller, the

```
public Task UpdateAsync(TUser user)
```

method is called instead of

```
 public Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
```

How could this be? Is it a known bug? Could I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the "update" method is called, after which a select statement checks if the record is present in the table. If not (the select returns null), the Usermanager will do a create for the new record.